# Ruby on Rails - Paperclip getting Image

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image, controller, paperclip

i'm using Paperclip to handle the uploading of my photos to my App but am having some issues retrieving them

I can add/remove/display all images successfully but how can I retrieve only one photo of my model? Like, the first one?

To retrieve them all, im using:

```
<%= form_for @hotel, :html => {:multipart => true} do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :hphotos do |hp|%>
     <%= image_tag(hp.object.hphoto.url(:medium))%>
  <%end%>
<%end%>
```

which works fine, but in my index, I only want to show one photo for each hotel displayed.
im getting :

```
undefined method `Hphotos'
I also ran across: undefined method `url' when testing
```

I suspect the issue is in my controller, but as im not sure what, here it is (i'm also putting the create action, which works fine)

```
 def index

   @hotels= Hotel.search(params)
   @hotels= <pagination>
#I think the issue is here
   @hotels.Hphotos.build #changing to @hotels.Hphoto.build or @hotels.hphotos.build won't work and I think my issue is here.
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html 
      format.json { render :json => @hotels }
    end
  end
```

This works fine:

```
def new
    @hotel = Hotel.new
    2.times { @hotel.hphotos.build }
end
```

I'm doing this on my index view:

```
<% @hotels.each do |hotel|%>
(...)
<%= image_tag hotel.hphoto.url(:small) %>
(...)
<%end%>
```

Like I said, I only wished to retrieve the first image, but even in the index I can't get them all, so I think the issue is with the controller.

Thanks for reading, any tips are welcome, im kind of stuck :)

regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your index view, you're calling hotel.hphoto but it should be hphotos since it's a one to many relationship. If you want the first one, you should do:

```
hotel.hphotos.first.url(:small)
```

Comment: I'm getting `undefined method url`. Any ideas?